# format marker shape in line chart matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, powerbi, linechart

I am very new to python and looking to customize a line chart.

I am using the python visual within power bi to chart the points in a tennis match. I am using the following code, which works, to produce a simple chart:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
dataset.plot(kind='line', x = 'Index', y = 'Running total', marker = 'o')
plt.show()
```

[image: Screenshot]

Within my dataset, I have another column [Shot] that shows the type of shot used to finish the point (e.g. ace, error, winner, etc). I would like to change the shape of the marker based on the type of shot. e.g. circle for ace, x for error, triangle for winner).

I suspect I will need to use a for loop, but i am struggling to figure out how to construct this.

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

TIA!

Tried different ways of including a for loop but struggling to get the syntax correct

| Index | Running Total | Score type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | Forced error |
| 2 | 1 | Winner |
| 3 | 2 | Ace |
| 4 | 1 | Double fault |
| 5 | 2 | Forced error |
| 6 | 3 | Ace |
| 7 | 4 | Forced error |
| 8 | 3 | Forced error |
| 9 | 2 | Winner |
| 10 | 1 | Double fault |

Comment: this is categorical data which you can do in the `seaborn` module. Alternatively, post a sample of the data int the question and we can help.

Comment: Many thanks @D.L for your reply. I will take a look at the seaborn documentation. I have also edited the question to include a table with some sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the update and the data. With the data that you have given you can achieve this with a scatter plot.

here is an example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create the dataframe
data = {'Index': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
        'Running Total': [0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1],
        'Score type': ['Forced error', 'Winner', 'Ace', 'Double fault', 
                       'Forced error', 'Ace', 'Forced error', 'Forced error', 
                       'Winner', 'Double fault']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# plot the line chart
plt.plot(df['Index'], df['Running Total'], '-')

# plot the scatter chart
categories = df['Score type'].astype("category").cat.categories
for i, category in enumerate(categories):
    plt.scatter(df[df['Score type'] == category]['Index'],
                df[df['Score type'] == category]['Running Total'],
                label=category, c=f"C{i}")

plt.xlabel('Index')
plt.ylabel('Running Total')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

and this is the result:

[image]

You can see that i plotted the chart in two parts.

1. line chart
2. scatter plot

Comment: Many thanks for this.... It works perfectly! If I were to look to change the colour of the line based on 2 different values (eg based on who won the point) is this possible using matplotlib?

Comment: yes,  absolutely it would be too. There are a few ways of achieving this, so it would probably be best suited to a new question if you could not find the answer yourself too...  I am glad to have helped. Please do mark the answer as accepted so that others can benefit.